# Synthesized getter not working for instance variables of type NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, getter, synthesize

Hi I'm a newbie in `Objective-C` programming. Today I was writing a program and I'm quite confused with the way it behaves. Here is the program :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyClass:NSObject
{
    NSString * str;
}
@property NSString * str;
@end;

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize str;
@end

int main()
{   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    MyClass * obj = [[MyClass alloc]init];
    [obj setStr: @"hello"];
    /* the following lines of code will give error if not commented but why it is                    
     resulting in error  ?????
      NSLog(@"Str = %@",[obj getStr]); // **gives error if not commented** 
      **or**
      NSString * temp;
      temp = [obj getStr]; // gives error
      NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    */
    NSString * temp;
    temp = obj.str;
    NSLog(@"%@",temp); // works just fine 
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

In main function when I try to print the str value using `getStr` a synthesized accessor it gives me error. Why so? Are we not allowed to use synthesized `getter` for `NSString` or am I not using the `getter` in a correct way?? But still the synthesized `setter` `[obj setStr]` sets the value for `NSString` type. 
I saw some answers here and there for this kind of questions on stack overflow but I really din't understand the answer which were provided there so please explain this in a simple manner for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the synthesized getter for property `xyz` is the same as the name of the property, i.e. `xyz`. It is *not* `getXyz`. Only the setter gets prefixed with a "set", becoming `setXyz:`

That is why your code

```
NSLog(@"Str = %@",[obj getStr]);
```

does not compile. Changing to

```
NSLog(@"Str = %@",[obj str]);
```

will fix the problem.

Note: when you let Xcode synthesize a property for you, a variable to "back" that property is also created. You do not need to declare an instance variable `str` in addition to the property `str`.

Comment: Tnx alot . I din't know the  name of the synthesized getter for property xyz is the same as the name of the property. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

This is not getter method call `temp = [obj getStr];`.  Getter method is trigger by either `[obj str])` or dot notation `obj.str`. But you can define `getStr`, if you do, then use as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to access getter and setter of a property:

```
//getter
NSLog(@"Str = %@",self.str);

//setter
self.str = @"hello";
```